# Array of Matrices with Different sizes in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, size

I am trying to make an array of say 3 matrices with different sizes:

```
Array ={ {{1, 2, 3}, {10, 20, 30}},
         {{4, 5}, {40, 50}, {400, 500}},
         {{6, 7}, {60, 70}} };
```

I need to use **array indexing** rather than pointer arithmetic for my codes.

I think I should create a 1-d array containing 3 pointers to matrices. Something like:

```
{ *ptr1[3], *ptr2[2], *ptr3[2]}
```

But how can I declare such an object? Also how can I assign values to that?

I am readying the actual data from a binary file using `fread`.

Thank you,

Comment: How are you going to know the size of each matrix in the array of matrices?  All the elements of an array in C are homogeneous — the same type.  That probably means you need an array of a structure type where each structure describes the shape of its array and contains a suitable pointer to the data.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have all the sizes in a separate array in the binary file. I do know that it is possible to have arrays of arrays with different sizes in C using array of pointers. But I am wondering how to generalise that in my codes to higher dimensions in order to have an array of matrices with different sizes!

Comment: Oh, so that makes life trivial — well, sort of.  Your `Array` is `void *Array[] = { ptr1, ptr2, ptr3 };` (or if the arrays are all of type "array of `int`", you can use `int *Array[] = { &ptr1[0][0], &ptr2[0][0], &ptr3[0][0] };`, or similar.  You can use compound literals if need be to create the arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Jagged array is array of arrays such that member arrays can be of different sizes, i.e., we can create a 2-D array but with a variable number of columns in each row.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main() 
{ 
    int Mat1row0[3] = { 1, 2, 3}; 
    int Mat1row1[3] = {10, 20, 30}; 
    
    int Mat2row0[2] = {4, 5}; 
    int Mat2row1[2] = {40, 50}; 
    int Mat2row2[2] = {400, 500};
    
    int Mat3row0[2] = {6, 7}; 
    int Mat3row1[2] = {60, 70}; 
    
    
    int* jagged1[2] = {Mat1row0, Mat1row1 }; 
    int* jagged2[3] = {Mat2row0, Mat2row1, Mat2row2};
    int* jagged3[2] = {Mat3row0, Mat3row1 };
    
    int** jaggedkk[3] = {jagged1, jagged2, jagged3};

    
   printf("%d",jaggedkk[0][0][0]);

    return 0;

}
```

The output is : 1

Comment: @Ramtin  I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: In your codes, there are many useless variables like `Mat1row0`, `jagged1` etc. I was thinking of declaring all of them in one line. Something similar to `int** jaggedkk[3] = {jagged1, jagged2, jagged3};`

Comment: I used them for more clarity for new users.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a struct to represent a matrix and then create an array of that struct. Further, you would need a function for initializing a matrix (i.e. allocate memory) and also a function for deleting a matrix (i.e. free allocated memory).

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    size_t rows;
    size_t columns;
    int **data;
} Matrix;

void initMatrix(size_t rows, size_t columns, Matrix *m)
{
    if (rows == 0 || columns == 0) exit(1); // error

    // Allocate row pointers
    m->data = malloc(rows * sizeof m->data[0]);
    if (m->data == NULL) exit(1); // error

    // Allocate data area, i.e. rows x columns ints
    m->data[0] = malloc(rows * columns * sizeof m->data[0][0]);
    if (m->data[0] == NULL) exit(1); // error

    // Initialize the remaining row pointers
    for (size_t i=1; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        m->data[i] = m->data[0] + i * columns;
    }

    m->rows = rows;
    m->columns = columns;
}

void deleteMatrix(Matrix *m)
{
    free(m->data[0]);
    free(m->data);
    m->rows = 0;
    m->columns = 0;
    m->data = NULL;
}

void printMatrix(Matrix *m)
{
    printf("---------------------------\n");
    printf("rows=%zu columns=%zu\n", m->rows, m->columns);
    for (size_t i=0; i < m->rows; ++i)
    {
        printf("row[%zu] at %p\t", i, (void*)m->data[i]);
        for (size_t j=0; j < m->columns; ++j)
        {
            printf("%d\t", m->data[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("---------------------------\n");
}

int main(void) 
{
    Matrix m[2];
    
    initMatrix(2, 5, &m[0]);
    for(size_t i=0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        for(size_t j=0; j < 5; ++j)
        {
            m[0].data[i][j] = 10*i + j;
        }
    }
    
    initMatrix(3, 2, &m[1]);
    for(size_t i=0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for(size_t j=0; j < 2; ++j)
        {
            m[1].data[i][j] = 100 + 10*i + j;
        }
    }

    for(size_t i=0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        printMatrix(&m[i]);
    }
    
    for(size_t i=0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        deleteMatrix(&m[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Possible output:

```
---------------------------
rows=2 columns=5
row[0] at 0x1979030 0   1   2   3   4   
row[1] at 0x1979044 10  11  12  13  14  
---------------------------
---------------------------
rows=3 columns=2
row[0] at 0x1979080 100 101 
row[1] at 0x1979088 110 111 
row[2] at 0x1979090 120 121 
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

A 'short/simple' solution could be just to write:

```
int *** Array =(int**[]){ (int*[]){(int[]){1, 2, 3}, (int[]){10, 20, 30}},
     (int*[]){(int[]){4, 5}, (int[]){40, 50}, (int[]){400, 500}},
     (int*[]){(int[]){6, 7}, (int[]){60, 70}} };
```

Now  Array[0][0][0] will be 1, Array[2][1][1] will be 70, etc;
If you need to do it dynamically, you can do it the following way:

```
int *** Array;

Array = malloc(sizeof(int**)*3);
Array[0] = malloc(sizeof(int*)*2);
Array[0][0] = malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
Array[0][0][0] = 1;
...
(and so on)
```